# How do I stop the "USB computer connection" settings page popping up every time I plug my phone into a computer?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

When I plug my phone (An "imo Q2" which is apparently "powered by verve connect" and which runs Android 6) into a computer, I get a dialog titled "USB computer connection" popping up.  Given that I almost always want to use it either (1) for ADB or (2) just for charging, this dialog is useless to me.  I'd much rather it worked the way my *last* phone did, and just put a notification in the status bar that I can use to open it.  I've tried selecting the "always use these settings" option at the bottom, but it still pops up every time.

How do I disable this?